# View row data in modal when click andchor in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm newbie ini react.js, I have datatable that show the data, and I want show the data (name and email) on modal when click anchor in column

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.data.map(function(d, i){
    return <tr>
      <td>{d.name}</td>
      <td>{d.email}</td>
      <td><a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onClick={() => this.modalDetail(d.address)}>Detail</a></td>
    </tr>
  })}
</tbody>
```

And if I clicked Detail, modal is show, but show alert

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalDetail' of undefined

I have set modalDetail in constructor to

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      alerts: []
        };

        this.modalDetail = this.modalDetail.bind(this);
  }
```

Any help me? I am familiar with vue.js, so confused when I react.js

Comment: Where did you declare `modalDetail` function?

Comment: `modalDetail(datas) {
  console.log(datas)
  window.$('#exampleModal').modal('show')
 }`

I have declare modalDetail function

Comment: I may be wrong but I suppose that `this` in your call refers to `a` object. This error sure comes from context misuse.

Comment: @lazy.lizard, when I remove `this` instead appears error like this

```Failed to compile
./src/components/admin/pages/test.js
  Line 107:  'modalDetail' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Comment: I'm sure you don't need `a` tag here. Try to use `onClick` with `div` element just to test that `this` refers to correct context.

Comment: it's still error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'modalDetail' of undefined```

Comment: Here are 2 key moments. First, if you you use `.bind()` method you don't need to use arrow function in `onClick` - use `onClick={this.modalDetail(d.address)}`. Second, be sure to declare your `modalDetail` in class body and make it simple, just to `console` inside to make sure that is works. 

To be sure that your fucntion is in your context just `console.log(this.modalDetail)` inside your `map` - it must not be `udefined`.

Hope this helps.